# Sync framework get conflicting row data

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using *Sync Framework* to sync two *Sql Server* databases.

When some conflict is detected I catch the event and do some logic to resolve it, but I cant get the row data of the conflict.

So my question is, how can I get the specific conflicting data in the row that are about to synchronize?

The following code illustrates what I am doing:

```
if (e.Conflict.Type == DbConflictType.LocalInsertRemoteInsert)
{
     DataTable conflictingRemoteChange = e.Conflict.RemoteChange;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What you need is to know exactly which values in the row are in conflict? Or just get the row in conflict? Which provider are you using and what is the event do you handle?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. 
I need to know both, the values in conflict and the row in conflict too.
Im using SqlSyncProvider

Comment: And im handle the event ApplyChangesFailed

Comment: as Chris mentioned, you can only get the rows in conflict. it will not tell you which columns are in conflict. Sync Framework change tracking is at row level. it simply logs that a row has changed and doesn't care what changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `ApplyChangeFailed` event is raised by `SqlSyncProvider`, you use the `DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs` object which provides information about the error or conflict that caused the failure. The `e.conflict` property contains moreover:

- RemoteChange: Gets the `DataTable` object that contains the
  conflicting rows from the remote database.
- LocalChange: Gets the `DataTable` object that contains the conflicting rows from the local database.

These tables contain each one at most one row that represents the row in conflict.

```
Datarow drRemote = e.Conflict.RemoteChange.Rows[0];
Datarow drLocal = e.Conflict.LocalChange.Rows[0];
```

---

To get the specific value in conflict in the row, I'm afraid there is no other way that manually comparing of each value from the `DataRow`s.

**EDIT** : @JuneT says that better than I ;-)

> You can only get the rows in conflict. it will not tell you which
>   columns are in conflict. Sync Framework change tracking is at row
>   level. it simply logs that a row has changed and doesn't care what
>   changed.